# how to parse twitter API v2 timestamps to python datetime

Tags: python, datetime, parsing, twitter, timestamp

Twitter API v2 specifies how their timestamps are formated [here](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-ads-api/timezones).

An example of a timestamp from a tweet's `created_at` is: `2021-12-31T12:34:56.000Z`

**Question:** How to parse this format with python's datetime?

Answer (score 6):

This can be achieved by knowing that the `.000` refers to the microseconds and `Z` to the UTC timezone, and using an adaptation of the ISO-8601 format `"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ"`:

```py
from datetime import datetime

# or: tweet["data"]["created_at"] from the API
tweet_created_at = "2021-12-31T12:34:56.000Z" 

dt = datetime.strptime(tweet_created_at ,"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")
print(dt) # outputs: 2021-12-31 12:34:56
```